# How to make API for website that is not mine and also requires a login?

Tags: react-native, api, authentication

I'm trying to create a react native app that uses data from a website that is not mine. I need to enter a login and password to get into this website.

I was thinking about using a web scraper on the backend to accomplish this, but I wasn't sure this was the best approach or even possible. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you could find the API from the network tabs, then use that API instead. Web Scrapers are more prone to be unstable, you wouldn't want to change the scraper again and again if someone from the website changes something in their UI. Reach out for API first, scraper should be your last option.

Comment: I couldn't find the API in the network tabs. Do you know if there's a way to create an api that web scrapes with a login?

Comment: If it's performing login on form submit, check out the page source, and look about the function attached to the form submit handler. If it's a JS rendered app, then you should find the API there. Moreover, if it's a static HTML site, use `cheerio` to scrape and emulate a form submit otherwise use puppeteer. Also, if you use a scraper, there is a higher chances that you need to change the code over and over again when the site you're scraping changes.